# Post logout How to clear cookies “SMSESSION” and “SMIDENTITY”?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, siteminder

We have an issue with log out functionality. On log off the cookies “SMSESSION” and “SMIDENTITY” are not getting cleared. Hence on reload, site minder is unable to reset SMSESSION cookie value to “LOGGEDOFF”. This is causing issues on multiple logins/logout using the same browser.

Looks like the cookies are not being cleared.Also is there a SiteMinder end point that can clear off the cookies and we can call this from logout function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a LogOffUri set in your ACO.  Just redirect the user to this page from your logout function and the session will be cleared.